# Why read operation isn't working in this code?

Tags: python

I am learning python file operations and was experimenting with different options to read and write.
As far as I know this code should be able to both append and read from test.txt file as I have opened it with "a+". But though the append operation is working as expected, I am not getting any output from the print function.

> ```
> my_file = open('test.txt', 'a+') 
> my_file.write("You know nothin' Jon Snow.") 
> content = my_file.read() 
> print(content)
> my_file.close()
> ```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You do not understand how files work. When opening a file with `'a+'` you open the file and write something at its end. The filestreampointer is at the end of the file - if you read something there is nothing to read. You need to close/open the file or seek() to a position before the end to read something from it.

Comment: Yes that didn't come to my mind. I know this is how files work, forgot it due to lack of practice for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

When you first open the file, the file pointer is at the end of the file. The write leaves the file pointer following the new text. When you try to read, there's nothing *left* to read; you are already at the end of the file. If you wanted to read the entire contents of the file, you would need to seek to the beginning before reading.

```
with open('test.txt', 'a+') as my_file:
    my_file.write("You know nothin' Jon Snow.") 
    my_file.seek(0)
    content = my_file.read() 
    print(content)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because after you do the write you are now positioned at the end of the file so when you do a read operation there is nothing to read. You need to do first do a `seek` to position yourself somewhere before the end of file:

```
my_file = open('test.txt', 'a+')
my_file.write("You know nothin' Jon Snow.")
my_file.seek(0)
content = my_file.read()
print(content)
my_file.close()
```

Comment: Append mode is irrelevant; if `w+` had been used, the file would be truncated, and the file pointer would *still* be at the end of the file after the write.

Comment: @chepner That is certainly true.